# Как занести содержимое файла в объект с помощью Ajax?

Tags: ajax, javascript, http, https, get

Начал изучать ajax,  но так и не понял, как занести содержимое файла `https://a.ru/file.file` в объект theMyObject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем ясно, что именно Вы хотите получить. Но как мне кажется, Вы пытаетесь с домена A получить данные с домена B, что запрещено политикой безопасности браузеров. Если это так, то почитайте про формат JSONP, он позволяет делать кроссдоменные запросы.

P.S. Для ясности вопроса - код в студию!).

Comment: ---
Ок, я пытаюсь сделать бота для твиттера, КОТОРЫЙ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАТЬ БУДУ ТОЛЬКО Я. Ну и мне надо считать, что там не передаёт твиттер. Парсер я напишу без проблем, то нужно иметь - что парсить. p.s. а как работает расширение Dev HTTP Client, написанное на JS, которое может делать любые запросы

Comment: Если Вы хотите сделать бота на Javascript, то Вам нужно делать расширение для хрома, иначе же Вы упрётесь в Политику безопасности кроссдоменных запросов. Вообще такие вещи нужно делать на серверных языках. Если есть познания PHP и cURL, то написать такого бота не составит труда.